# After deploying class, it will throw Insufficient Privileges while working

Tags: apex

> Insufficient Privileges
>
> You do not have the level of access necessary
> to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
> the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

This problem I am facing every time after deployed the class.

```
public Class classA {
}
```

I checked security to class, which is enabled to all profiles

Comment: Can you give us more information? What kind of class is it? when you get this error?

Comment: If you introduce your own class called `Test` this will hide any unqualified references to http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm. I can't see how that would cause your problem; just best to avoid (or always use `System.Test` to access the platform's class).

Comment: Ah..the same issue what i got on the other day..you only helped me. Thanks, @KeithC Thanks for pointing out this issue here.

Comment: Are you having issues if you deploy **ANY** class, or is it just this one?

Comment: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000163404&language=en_US this is the similar scenario, but I am not getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the issue with version number!! for us it worked fine after having same version number :)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question... can you clarify how @Bharat?

Comment: @LaceySnr , It was happened like the after the class is implemented/modified/deployed then the field in Opportunity  is created so the version of Opportunity created is high(Ex 30) and the class version is 27 or low ..then it thrown error for insufficient privileges...

Comment: Thanks for the info Uday... much more useful for those who find this answer in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

1. try `public without sharing` or
2. while deploying your class, do not forget to include the profiles for which you want to give access or

**3. create a sharing rule (for example on the Account records) which will give the users or profiles with lesser privilege access to the records which has been created by the users with higher privilege. This will solve this issue.**

Comment: I tried with this, but it can't help

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, don't name your classes the same as System classes.  Salesforce already has a Test class so you should probably name it something different.

```
public Class test {
}
```

Change it to something like:

```
public Class TestCode {
}
```

The class name here is still pretty generic but at least you aren't naming it the same as a System class.  This might not be the reason you are having issues, but it will definitely help you moving forward.

EDIT: Seems like you updated your code to not use the name **Test** anymore so I guess this response isn't very valid.  I'll leave it though since it could potentially still be useful for someone else.

Comment: hey i just updated the question to avoid the confusion.. please have a look